# Change Class on first click of a button that opens a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am looking to have a button's icon class change only on the first click of the button event, which would also ajax .put a field to the db..

```
<div class="btn-group check-btns checkIt">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Tested this simple on.click first (http://jsfiddle.net/57268/1/), but thought that Bootstrap's  built-in dropdown .open class toggle might prevent this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
    $('.checkIt').on('click', function () {
```

But changing it to listen to the dropdown being shown has yet to work either http://jsfiddle.net/57268/:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
    $('.btn-group.check-btns.checkIt').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
            console.log('checkIt clicked');
            var $this = $(this);
          var $that = $(this).children('.check-btns').children('.btn').find('.glyphicon')
          if ($that.hasClass('.glyphicon-unchecked')) {
            $that.removeClass('.glyphicon-unchecked').addClass('.glyphicon-check');
            console.log('now checked icon');
            $this.removeClass('.checkIt').addClass('.checkedIt');
            console.log('now checkedIt class');
            alert('checked and checkedIt .. now an ajax .put call');
          }
      })
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TL35y/)</kbd>

`hasClass`, `removeClass`, `addClass` takes className not selector

eg. `$el.addClass('class')` is correct but not `$el.addClass('.class')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.checkIt').on('click', function () {
        console.log('checkIt clicked');
        var $this = $(this),
            $that = $(this).find('.glyphicon'); //changed to .find() only
        if ($that.hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked')) {
            $that.removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked').addClass('glyphicon-check');
            console.log('now checked icon');
            $this.removeClass('checkIt').addClass('checkedIt');
            console.log('now checkedIt class');
            alert('checked and checkedIt');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. It works nicely in the fiddle.. For whatever reason though, it has yet to log even the first checkIt clicked in the app.. Did forget to mention that this involves templating with handlebars, which may be intruding here.. So I tried binding it to the document (tends to be the solution with templating, but actually I just noticed that another addClass/removeClass focus event isn't working with the templating..quite curious - any suggestions?

Comment: Check your code for this problem eg. `$el.addClass('class')` is correct but not `$el.addClass('.class')`

Comment: first, thanks for that.. great catch.. Turns out it has to be bound to an element outside of the template for the click event eg.    $(".exterior-template-element").on("click", ".checkIt", function () {

Answer (score 0):

To explain Tushar's solution, your original code had two problems:

1. The chain for defining $that used .children('.check-btns') - this looks for an element with class check-btns inside $this element children, but $this is actually the div that already has this class (you are looking for an element inside its own children).
2. In hasClass, you are looking for class ".glyphicon-unchecked" - this is incorrent, the class name is actually "glyphicon-unchecked", the dot is used only when you need a selector.

Comment: Appreciate the pointers.. For whatever reason though, maybe something to do with templating (forgot to mention that this invovlves handlebars), even the first console.log has yet to appear.. any suggestions

Comment: Turns out it has to be bound to an element outside of the template for the click event eg. $(".exterior-template-element").on("click", ".checkIt", function () {.. Thanks again